# Custom TableView functions are not getting called?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

On my main.Storyboard I have a TableViewController which is set to a custom class with TableViewController.swift.

The swift file has all the tableview functions defined and the @IBOutlet for the UITableView connected.  The classes defined are UINavigationController,UITableViewDelegate.  This viewController is called from a secondViewController via the prepareForSegue function.

I also created CustomCell.swift with class UITableViewCell and all @IBOutlet for the labels in my UITableViewCell which has been set to the customCell class.

I can't paste all my code but if you need to look at any specific code let me know and I will be happy to post that.

The Build succeeds and the app runs but the tableviewcells don't show up and none of the tableview functions are called.  I see 2 flash animated screens - indicating that the tableviewcell might have 2 views - but can't figure out where I should be checking?

//Below is the segue function triggering the TableViewController

```
        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        //print("In prepareswgue: ",segue, " ",sender)
        if(segue.identifier == "resultSegue")
        {
            let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let svc = nav.topViewController as! TableViewController
            svc.serialNo = self.TSSerialNoField.text
    }
}


//Below is the custom TableVIewController class code
class TableViewController: UINavigationController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    var serialNo:String!
    var ashHardwareData: NSMutableArray!

    @IBOutlet var ResultTableView: UITableView!
    //@IBOutlet weak var LogCaseButton: UIButton!


    @IBOutlet weak var TypeResultLabel: UILabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.ResultTableView?.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
        self.ResultTableView?.delegate = self
        ResultTableView?.dataSource = self
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.getHardwareData(serialNo.uppercaseString)
    }

    /*override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
    }*/

    func getHardwareData(serialno:String)
    {
        ashHardwareData = NSMutableArray()
        ashHardwareData = ModelManager.getInstance().getHardwareData(serialno)
        ResultTableView?.reloadData()
    }
    //TableView Delegate Methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        print("In height func")
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(ashHardwareData.count)
        return ashHardwareData.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:ResultsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("results", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ResultsCell
        let hardware:HardwareInfo = ashHardwareData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! HardwareInfo
        let contract:ContractInfo = ashHardwareData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! ContractInfo
        cell.SNOLabel.text = "Serial N0: \(hardware.SerialNo)"
        cell.ContractIDLabel.text = "Contract ID: \(contract.ContractID)"
        cell.OrgLabel.text = "Organisation: \(hardware.Organisation)"
        cell.ModelLabel.text = "Model: \(hardware.Model)"
        if(contract.DaystoExpiry > 0) {
            cell.TypeLabel.text = "Contract Type: Active"
            self.TypeResultLabel.hidden = false
            self.TypeResultLabel.text = "To log a technical case for the Hardware please click on Log Technical Case button."
            cell.LogCaseButton.hidden = false
            cell.LogCaseButton.tag = indexPath.row
        }
        else {
            cell.TypeLabel.text = "Contract Type: Expired"
            cell.LogCaseButton.hidden = true
            self.TypeResultLabel.hidden = false
            self.TypeResultLabel.text = "Support Contract for the hardware expired.  Please contact Sales team to renew the contract."
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}


//here is the code for the ResultsCell custom UITableViewCell

    import Foundation
import UIKit

class ResultsCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var SNOLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var LogCaseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ContractIDLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var OrgLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var TypeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ModelLabel: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post some code, otherwise it´s hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: I have modified the Question with the code.  If you need anything more let me know.  Thanks for a quick reply

Comment: Why does your `TableViewController` extend `UINavigationController`? Why not `UIViewController` or even `UITableViewController`?

Comment: @Ashley Seems like you are not conforming `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, as result, `UITableViewDelegate` is not being called. On the other hand, have you consider to extend `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`?

Comment: @rmaddy - I tried using the UIViewController but because my custom viewController is trigered from a prepare segue function of a different ViewController I had to add UINavigatorController else it was giving an error.

Comment: @eMdOS - so I have to declare UITableViewDataSource in viewDidLoad()?  And what should it be declared as?

Comment: @eMdOS - I tried declaring the UITableViewDataSource as a subclass to the custom TableViewController and declaring the delegate to self.  The tableView functions are still not called.

Comment: @Ashley in the code you published I'm not seeing the `dataSource`, you have `self.ResultTableView?.delegate = self` but I'm not seeing `self.ResultTableView?.dataSource = self`. I don't know it you connected the `dataSource` in the `Interface Builder`, but if not, that is missing.

Comment: @eMdOS - here is the modified code - as I said I don't get any errors and when the screen loads from the SecondViewController from the PrepareSegue function - it appears as if it is loading 2 screens on top of each other - the last one showing just a black screen.  I tried breakpoints and print statements to see if it actually is hitting the tableView Functions and none of them get called:

Comment: Anyone out there who can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

have you configured `ResultsCell` in story board or in `view didload`. check it once. if not try to add the following code into your `view didload`

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ResultsCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ResultsCell"];
```

Comment: I am getting error if I declare your code in the viewDidLoad func.  I am using Swift with xcode 7.1.1.  It is asking me to put a ; after the : forCellReuseIdentifier.  I have ResultsCell.swift file declaring all the labels for displaying in the tableVIewCell

Comment: Try this one,                                                           self.tableView.registerClass(ResultsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

Answer (score 0):

I have spent fair bit of my time trying to get this issue resolved and decided to go without the tableviewcell, instead I have created custom viewControllers and defined labels to display the results from the DB search (which is working OK) and used the perform segue function to pass values between viewcontrollers.  So now my app works the way I want - maybe not ideal from a programming side but due to time constraints I had to get this working.
I have my app as a Tabbed Application with First and Second ViewControllers.  The FirstViewController adds data to the SQLLite DB and the Second searches for the data and displays the results. for displaying the results I created a Custom viewController with labels for the data that I wanted displayed and passed all data from the DB results in SecondViewController functions to it and updated the labels with the data.  As long as I get the results I wanted I am happy.  I will re-visit this for improvement if I have to.  Thanks to all who responded with solutions and suggestions.  It has been a good learning experience :)